# AutoMapper: ignore some parameters when calling the Map() function

Tags: c#, automapper

I want to ignore some mappings while I call the Map function.

Here's where I create my Map:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<User, UserViewModel>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.WebLicenseCount, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => GetCount(src, "0801")))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.MobileLicenseCount, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => GetCount(src, "0901")))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.ExcelAddInLicenseCount, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => GetCount(src, "0895")))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.NextExpirationDate, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Licences.Min(l => l.LicenceProducts.Min(lp => lp.ExpirationDate))))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Licences, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Licences.ToList()))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.TicketsCount, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Tickets.Count(t => t.Status != (int)TicketStatusType.Closed)))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.ParentContact, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Contact))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.ParentUser, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.User2))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Contacts, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Contacts))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.MainContact, opt => opt.Ignore())
    .ForMember(dest => dest.SessionID, opt => opt.Ignore())
    ;
```

In my controller I do this:

```
users = Mapper.Map<UserViewModel[]>(response.users);
```

I want to ignore in this call, the mapping for those proprieties :`WebLicenseCount`, `MobileLicenseCount`, `ExcelAddInLicenseCount`.

There's anyway to do this?

Comment: I'm not sure if that's possible; have you considered an alternative, like having `GetCount` check if the state is right before trying to get the count?

Comment: The create map is done at the beggining in the globalSettings. So, it's done at the beginning of the program. I think that I'm going to create a new model that will have the same attributes as UserViewModel, but will have no Count properties.

Comment: I know, but you could put the check inside `GetCount`.

Comment: How I will do the check inside. What kind of parameter will do that for me?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If this is something you want to do only once then overwrite the mentioned properties in users with the corresponding response.users after the Map() function. If this is something you would want to do often then it means you either need to change your mapping or create a second type (e.g. SpecialUser) for those situations and define different set of mappings for this type.

Comment: Hmm, Two down votes on an accepted answer with no explanation and no proposed alternatives? How classy of you.